# cannot start iphone simulator using calabash-ios

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, calabash

I've been searching for a solution to this for a few hours now, and I can't seem to find my problem reported anywhere else, so here goes...

First, about my environment:

```
localhost:calabash-ios-example jenkins$ xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
localhost:calabash-ios-example jenkins$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 5.1.1
Build version 5B1008
localhost:calabash-ios-example jenkins$ calabash-ios version
0.9.168
irb(main):001:0> Calabash::Cucumber::FRAMEWORK_VERSION
"0.9.168"
```

I know I should also provide the server_version, but I cannot get that... see below..

So, my issue is that I canNOT start the simulator. At first, I was getting ECONNREFUSED, quickly enough, I realized I needed to set APP_BUNDLE_PATH, so that's sorted now.

However, when I do try to run my tests, the simulator tries to start, stays up for a few seconds, then crashes, and restarts... And I get the following error message:

```
localhost:<path> jenkins$ APP_BUNDLE_PATH="build/<app>-cal.app" cucumber
0:35: execution error: iPhone Simulator got an error: Application isn’t running. (-600)
Feature: 
  XXXXXX

  @reset
  Scenario: Test I can login as the cucumber user.                       # features/accounts/login.feature:7
0:35: execution error: iPhone Simulator got an error: Application isn’t running. (-600)
```

I even try to start the test server through the console and I get:

```
irb(main):001:0> start_test_server_in_background
0:35: execution error: iPhone Simulator got an error: Application isn’t running. (-600)
```

Would appreciate any help, as I can't seem to find any info anywhere else and I'm pretty stuck on this...

As a final note, I'd like to note it looks like an environment issue because I can't even get the sample app to work...